# insert a new row in R based on time interval checking

Tags: r, time, intervals

ALL; 
I just have a data file with two columns, one is time series, one is values. Normally, the time interval between tow rows is exact 5 mins,but sometimes it is larger than 5 mins

A sample is as below:

```
    dd <- data.table(date = c("2015-07-01 00:00:00", "2015-07-01 00:05:00", "2015-07-01 00:20:00","2015-07-01 00:25:00","2015-07-01 00:30:00"),
         value = c(9,1,10,12,0))
```

what i want to do is to check the time interval between two rows, when the time interval is larger than 5 mins, then insert a new row below with 0 value, so , the result could be :

```
    date                  value
    2015-07-01 00:00:00    9
    2015-07-01 00:05:00    1
    2015-07-01 00:10:00    0
    2015-07-01 00:15:00    0
    2015-07-01 00:20:00    10
    2015-07-01 00:25:00    12
    2015-07-01 00:30:00    0
```

any suggestion and idea is welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a join after converting to 'date' to DateClass

```
dd[, date := as.POSIXct(date)][]
dd[dd[, .(date=seq(min(date), max(date), by = "5 min"))], on = 'date'
        ][is.na(value), value := 0][]
#                  date value
#1: 2015-07-01 00:00:00     9
#2: 2015-07-01 00:05:00     1
#3: 2015-07-01 00:10:00     0
#4: 2015-07-01 00:15:00     0
#5: 2015-07-01 00:20:00    10
#6: 2015-07-01 00:25:00    12
#7: 2015-07-01 00:30:00     0
```

Comment: Can whoever downvoted also comment on why he or she doesn't think this solves the question?

Comment: It is also not clear why the question got down voted without any comment.